# Mx5 Intermittent Starting Issue

Tags: miata

I have a 1998 Nb Miata which has recently been having issues starting. There have only been two cases of this occurring in the last month. The first occurrence it cranked but wouldn't start, I opened the hood didn't see anything out of place and tried again, to which it started.

The second was more severe, after about 20 minutes of trying to get it going it only cranked, with an occasional sputter of ignition. I don't think its the ignition as spraying engine starter into the intake started it. I assumed it was the fuel system, pulled out the fuel pump then put it back in, went to buy a new one but nowhere was open when I tried the car again it started.

Apart from these two occurrences, the car runs with perhaps the only caveat that it gets close to stalling when coasting and idles low at startup (~500-700), however idling while stopped is fine. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your fuel filter?

Comment: My guess is stuck open check valve in fuel pump. If you turn key to on, let fuel pump run for ten-fifteen seconds does car ALWAYS start?